# Script to format a range of cells and insert a specific text based on a date in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a planner type Google spreadsheet where data added daily by 8-10 users. When I add a date to a cell, I want all the cells in the same row after that date to be formatted and added a text value something like "ENDED".

At the moment I am doing it with conditional formatting and with an ArrayFormula to add the text value. The problem is that for the ArrayFormula to work the cells must be empty and in my sheet the cells they might contain data before the "ENDED" date cell.

Is there a way to do this with a script?.... and if the script can handle also the formatting of the cells that will be the best solution.

Here is my sample file to understand better what I am trying to do...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QplyEcNu-svYwFq9wvPVEKnsEP1AnrlAkbBxNwEFPXg/edit#gid=2087617521

Comment: Can you provide the result you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike look at the link and change the date in column B row 3 and you'll see what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. When I saw the shared Spreadsheet, I had already been able to understand about it. But unfortunately, even under that situation, I cannot understand about the detail of OP's goal. But I thought that I would like to support to achieve it. So I asked about it. This is due to my poor understanding. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: For anyone whom it's interesting about this, [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58378575/script-to-automatically-insert-a-specific-text-in-cells-of-a-google-spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a trigger and a custom function.

Create a new apps script project and use this code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() ==2) {
    //User edited the date column
    if (typeof e.range.getValue() === typeof new Date()) {
      //Value of edit was a date
      endColumns(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getValue());
    } else if (e.range.getValue() === ""  || e.range.getValue() === null) {
      var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var resetRange = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn()+1, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns()-e.range.getColumn());
      resetRange.clear(); //Will delete all text, not only the "ENDED" text.
    }
  }
}

function endColumns(rowNum, limitDate) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var colOffset = 3; //Offset to account for your row Headers
  var dateHeader = sheets.getRange(1, colOffset, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns()-colOffset);

  var availableDates = dateHeader.getValues()[0];

  var foundCol = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<availableDates.length; i++) {
    if (availableDates[i]>=limitDate) {
      break;
    }
    foundCol++;
  }

  var rewriteCells = sheets.getRange(rowNum, foundCol+colOffset, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns()-(foundCol+colOffset));

  //Add your formatting and text below:
  rewriteCells.setValue("Ended");
  rewriteCells.setBackground("red");
  rewriteCells.setFontColor("yellow");

  //Clear all cells that are "white" (no header)
  for (var i=0; i<availableDates.length; i++) {
    if (availableDates[i]==="" || availableDates[i] ===null) {
      sheets.getRange(rowNum, colOffset+i).clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Then, create a trigger to run the `onEdit` function on every edit.

In this case there are some hardcoded values:

- `e.range.getColumn() == 2` for the row where you add the dates on
- `var colOffset = 3` for the number of columns to skip before reading the dates

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ZektorH. If this means that i will need to edit the hard coded values of the script for every row and date, unfortunately that's not a go for me. In my spreadsheet sample above there only 3 rows so i can demonstrate what i am trying to do, but in my actual working file there are dozens of rows and about 10-12 sheets. Like i said before, currently i am doing it with an ArrayFormula by copying & paste the formula to each expired date and i was hoping to avoid that with the help of a script. In any case thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Hello @NessusB, the hard-coded values only reference the row where you have your dates at (Row 1) and the column where you fill in the dates manually (Column B).  This solution should work for your sheet, as I have tested with a copy of it myself. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey @ZektorH. I am deeply sorry for not understanding your answer. You are right. Your code It works perfectly and it's exactly what i was looking for. There is only one downside. As you can see in my sample file i have an empty column to separate each week from each other and the script also fills the cells in those columns. Can we avoid that?. Also besides the inserted text (ENDED) can i also format the cells? eg different color for the text & the background, so get rid also the condional formating?, Thanks again for your help.

Comment: EDIT. Sorry i've forgot this... Is it possible when i delete the date from column B also all the marked and formatted cells to be cleared?. I notice that currently if i delete a date the marked cells with the inserted text are staying there and i have to delete them manually.

Comment: @NessusB yes, it is possible to do so. But you might run into the problem where you delete the comments as well, not only the ENDED fields. Anyhow, you can see how to do that [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#clearContent())

Comment: Hey @ZektorH, thanks for the reply. Which comments do you mean?. There will be no other comments inside the marked cells as ENDED. Can you tell me where and how to put this code so it will clear only the marked cells?. Sorry but i am very new to this and my syntax knowledges are very limited. Also, what about the marked cells in the gaps between the weeks?. Any solution for that?

Comment: @NessusB I've updated my answer to address both points. Remember to accept the answer that help you.

Comment: Yes @ZektorH, sure but sorry man... this is not working as i expected. This it clears everything in the whole row. Even the lines around the cells!!!. I dont want that. I want it to clear only the cells containing the text ENDED. Let's forget about the formating. If is possible please make it like this.... add ONLY the texts (minus the weeks gaps) to the cells when the date is added to column B and when the date there is deleted,  clear ONLY the texts from ONLY those cells.

Comment: Hello @NessusB. Sorry to break it to you, but this is sounding a lot like free work. Please try to implement this yourself. The code is commented and the relevant parts are highlighted.

Comment: Ah... ok. No problem man. I'll try to do that although it will be very difficult for me to make it work. So, if some one else can step up and help me with this, by all means please do so, otherwise i will stick with my current way with the ArrayFormula. In any case thanks a lot @ZektorH for your help so far.

Comment: @NessusB `if some one else can step up and help me with this` Stackoverflow is not a forum to look for people to code for you. If you are struggling with implementation of code, [create a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) explaining what you have tried and the errors you are getting. If an answer someone has given you has been heplful also make sure to mark is as accepted so that other users with the same or similar issues in the future can also find the answers they are looking for.

Comment: For anyone whom it's interesting about this, [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58378575/script-to-automatically-insert-a-specific-text-in-cells-of-a-google-spreadsheet).