# Script to automatically insert a specific text in cells of a Google spreadsheet, based on a date in another cell, on the same row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script provided by @ZektorH in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58250884/script-to-format-a-range-of-cells-and-insert-a-specific-text-based-on-a-date-in) of mine.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() ==2) {
    //User edited the date column
    if (typeof e.range.getValue() === typeof new Date()) {
      //Value of edit was a date
      endColumns(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getValue());
    } else if (e.range.getValue() === ""  || e.range.getValue() === null) {
      var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var resetRange = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn()+1, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns()-e.range.getColumn());
      resetRange.clear({contentsOnly: true}); //Will delete all text, not only the "ENDED" text.
    }
  }
}

function endColumns(rowNum, limitDate) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var colOffset = 3; //Offset to account for your row Headers
  var dateHeader = sheets.getRange(1, colOffset, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns()-colOffset);

  var availableDates = dateHeader.getValues()[0];

  var foundCol = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<availableDates.length; i++) {
    if (availableDates[i]>=limitDate) {
      break;
    }
    foundCol++;
  }

  var rewriteCells = sheets.getRange(rowNum, foundCol+colOffset, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns()-(foundCol+colOffset-1));

  //Add your formatting and text below:
  rewriteCells.setValue("ENDED");

  //Clear all cells that are "white" (no header)
  for (var i=0; i<availableDates.length; i++) {
    if (availableDates[i]==="" || availableDates[i] ===null) {
      sheets.getRange(rowNum, colOffset+i).clear();
    }
  }
}
```

The script is working correctly after some small edits, but there is still one problem. When you clear the value in the *date* cell (col B) on a row, the script will clear all values in all cells on that row.

This is an issue for me because many rows have important data in the cells prior to the `ENDED` date.

**Question**

What do I need to change in this script so that it will only clear the cells with the `ENDED` text, after clearing the *date cell*?

Comment: Have you checked the availableDates content? If you want to check the column with the "ENDED" text just iterate over it as you do with the availableDates.

Comment: Hey @Juan Bravo Roig... thank you for your answer. How do i do that?. I have no idea how to do the check that you mention. All my efforts so far (mostly trial-and-error) were for finding a way to check which cells contain the ENDED text and then clear them.

Comment: I've updated with an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reworked your code a bit, basically adding a condition to check whether the value in each cell equals "ENDED", and only deleting data if that's the case:

```
// Delete all "ENDED" values:
var resetRange = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns() - e.range.getColumn());
var resetValues = resetRange.getValues()[0];
for(var i = 0; i < resetValues.length; i++) {
  if(resetValues[i] == "ENDED") {
    var resetCell = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1 + i);
    resetCell.clearContent();
  }
}
```

And also this, which deletes corresponding "ENDED" values if you edit to a later date:

```
// Clear past dates if new date is later:
var beforeDate = sheets.getRange(rowNum, colOffset, 1, foundCol);
var beforeValues = beforeDate.getValues()[0];
for(var i = 0; i < beforeValues.length; i++) {
  if(beforeValues[i] == "ENDED") {
    sheets.getRange(rowNum, colOffset + i).clearContent();
  }  
}
```

So, full code would be like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 2) {
    //User edited the date column
    if (typeof e.range.getValue() === typeof new Date()) {
      //Value of edit was a date
      endColumns(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getValue());
    } else if (e.range.getValue() === ""  || e.range.getValue() === null) {
      var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      // Delete all "ENDED" values:
      var resetRange = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns() - e.range.getColumn());
      var resetValues = resetRange.getValues()[0];
      for(var i = 0; i < resetValues.length; i++) {
        if(resetValues[i] == "ENDED") {
          var resetCell = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1 + i);
          resetCell.clearContent();
        }
      }      
    }
  }
}

function endColumns(rowNum, limitDate) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var colOffset = 3; //Offset to account for your row Headers
  var dateHeader = sheets.getRange(1, colOffset, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns() - colOffset);

  var availableDates = dateHeader.getValues()[0];

  var foundCol = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < availableDates.length; i++) {
    if (availableDates[i] >= limitDate) {
      break;
    }
    foundCol++;
  }

  var rewriteCells = sheets.getRange(rowNum, foundCol + colOffset, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns() - (foundCol + colOffset - 1));

  //Add your formatting and text below:
  rewriteCells.setValue("ENDED");

  // Clear past dates if new date is later:
  var beforeDate = sheets.getRange(rowNum, colOffset, 1, foundCol);
  var beforeValues = beforeDate.getValues()[0];
  for(var i = 0; i < beforeValues.length; i++) {
    if(beforeValues[i] == "ENDED") {
      sheets.getRange(rowNum, colOffset + i).clearContent();
    }  
  }


  // Clear all cells that are "white" (no header)
  for (var i = 0; i < availableDates.length; i++) {
    if (availableDates[i] === "" || availableDates[i] === null) {
      sheets.getRange(rowNum, colOffset+i).clear();
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this is of any help to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Omila... this is exactly what i was looking for and with your explanations i finally (!) learned how it's done!!!. Thanks again, your help is greatly appreciated. By the way, as a bonus, is there a simple way via the script to lock/protect the marked cells ranges and unlock them when they cleared?.... or is more easy to do it with Google's protected ranges feature?.

Comment: You're most welcome. Yes, you can do this easily with Apps Script. Check this for more info: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection. And I'd advise you to create another question if you're having problems with that.

Comment: i give up!. I can't do it!. New question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58488350/11647021).