# Lock/Protect cells in a whole Google spreadsheet containing a specific text value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58390927/11647021)) which inserts a specific text value to a range of cells based on the date on the second column (B) in the same row.....

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 2) {
    //User edited the date column
    if (typeof e.range.getValue() === typeof new Date()) {
      //Value of edit was a date
      endColumns(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getValue());
    } else if (e.range.getValue() === ""  || e.range.getValue() === null) {
      var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      // Delete all "ENDED" values:
      var resetRange = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns() - e.range.getColumn());
      var resetValues = resetRange.getValues()[0];
      for(var i = 0; i < resetValues.length; i++) {
        if(resetValues[i] == "ENDED") {
          var resetCell = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1 + i);
          resetCell.clearContent();
        }
      }      
    }
  }
}

function endColumns(rowNum, limitDate) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var colOffset = 3; //Offset to account for your row Headers
  var dateHeader = sheets.getRange(1, colOffset, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns() - colOffset);

  var availableDates = dateHeader.getValues()[0];

  var foundCol = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < availableDates.length; i++) {
    if (availableDates[i] >= limitDate) {
      break;
    }
    foundCol++;
  }

  var rewriteCells = sheets.getRange(rowNum, foundCol + colOffset, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns() - (foundCol + colOffset - 1));

  //Add your formatting and text below:
  rewriteCells.setValue("ENDED");

  // Clear past dates if new date is later:
  var beforeDate = sheets.getRange(rowNum, colOffset, 1, foundCol);
  var beforeValues = beforeDate.getValues()[0];
  for(var i = 0; i < beforeValues.length; i++) {
    if(beforeValues[i] == "ENDED") {
      sheets.getRange(rowNum, colOffset + i).clearContent();
    }  
  }


  // Clear all cells that are "white" (no header)
  for (var i = 0; i < availableDates.length; i++) {
    if (availableDates[i] === "" || availableDates[i] === null) {
      sheets.getRange(rowNum, colOffset+i).clear();
    }
  }
}
```

I want these cells, containing that specific text value, to be lock/protect from edit/delete by any other user except me (which i am the owner of the file). If the date in second column (B) is deleted then the above script clears the text values and the cells should be available for editing from all users.

I've try many codes snippets to do this with no luck and the closest approach that i found is the bellow script, but it locks only one column and all the cells in that column. Not only those with a specific value...

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var CellRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var CellColumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn();

  if (CellColumn == 7){
    sheet.getRange(CellRow, CellColumn).setValue("ENDED");
    Browser.msgBox("YOU CANNOT ADD DATA HERE!");
  }
}
```

Any idea how can i lock only the cells containing that specific text value ("ENDED") and unlock/un-protect them when that value it's cleared?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow would be as following:

- Incorporate a function that when run, protects all cells of your range with the content "ENDED"
- Modify your existing onEdit() function by adding additional code that will check if the content of a cell in column B has been deleted

### Below is a sample:

```
function myStartFunction(){
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  //adapt according to your datarange
  var myRange=sheets.getRange(1,3,sheets.getLastRow(),sheets.getLastColumn());
  var values=myRange.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<values[0].length;j++){
      if(values[i][j]=="ENDED"){
        var cell=myRange.getCell(i+1,j+1);
        var protection = cell.protect();
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
      }
    }
  }       
}
function onEdit(e){
  //YOUR EXISTING CODE
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 2) {
    //User edited the date column
    if (typeof e.range.getValue() === typeof new Date()) {
      //Value of edit was a date
      endColumns(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getValue());
    } else if (e.range.getValue() === ""  || e.range.getValue() === null) {
      var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      // Delete all "ENDED" values:
      var resetRange = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns() - e.range.getColumn());
      var resetValues = resetRange.getValues()[0];
      for(var i = 0; i < resetValues.length; i++) {
        if(resetValues[i] == "ENDED") {
          var resetCell = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1 + i);
          resetCell.clearContent();
        }
      }      
    }  
  }

  //HERE COMES THE ADDITIONAL PART
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 2 &&  e.oldValue != "" && e.range.getValue() == "") {
    var row=e.range.getRow();
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var protections=sheets.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
     var protection = protections[i];
     if (protection.getRange().getRow()==row) {
       protection.remove();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE

To implement protection changes on each edit, you can modify the code as following:

```
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

function Open(){
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  //adapt according to your datarange
  var myRange=sheets.getRange(3,3,sheets.getLastRow(),sheets.getLastColumn());
  var values=myRange.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<values[0].length;j++){
      if(values[i][j]=="ENDED"){
        var cell=myRange.getCell(i+1,j+1);
        var protection = cell.protect();
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
      }
    }
  }
}



function onEdit(e) {  
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 2) {
    //User edited the date column
    if (typeof e.range.getValue() === typeof new Date()) {
      //Value of edit was a date
      endColumns(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getValue());
      // wait until the function endColumns() finished
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      var myRange=sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(),3,1,sheets.getLastColumn());
      var values=myRange.getValues();
      for(var j=0;j<values[0].length;j++){
        if(values[0][j]=="ENDED"){
          var cell=myRange.getCell(1,j+1);
          var protection = cell.protect();
          protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        }
      }      
    } else if (e.range.getValue() === ""  || e.range.getValue() === null) {
        // Delete all "ENDED" values:
        var resetRange = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1, 1, sheets.getMaxColumns() - e.range.getColumn());
        var resetValues = resetRange.getValues()[0];
        for(var i = 0; i < resetValues.length; i++) {
          if(resetValues[i] == "ENDED") {
            var resetCell = sheets.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1 + i);
            resetCell.clearContent();                                
          }
        }
      Logger.log('date removed');
      var row=e.range.getRow();
      var protections=sheets.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
      for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
        var protection = protections[i];
        if (protection.getRange().getRow()==row) {
          protection.remove();
         }
       }      
     }  
  }
}
function endColumns(rowNum, limitDate) {
...
}
```

Comment: Hey @ziganotschka... thank you very much for your answer but this is not working. I've incorporated your code as you said but, either i am doing something wrong or something is wrong with the code. The marked cells still can be edited by all users. [Here is a sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QplyEcNu-svYwFq9wvPVEKnsEP1AnrlAkbBxNwEFPXg) on how i incorporated your code.

Comment: I just tested your sample sheet and it works as intended: if I make a copy of your spreadsheet to my drive (so I will be the owner of the spreadsheet and script) and posterior share the spreadsheet with others - the onOpen trigger will work for them and all cells with content "ENDED" will be protected. Is it possible that your other users had the sheet already open before you modfied the code, so that the onOpen trigger did not work for them? I recommend you to replace the simple onOpen trigger by an installable one:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Also, do you want the protection to be set only on open, or also onEdit - e.g. if a new date is set while a user has the sheet already open?

Comment: Let me test it again by clossing and re-open the file from some other user and get back to you in couple mins. Yes, i would like the protection to be applied also if the date has changed and any user has the file opened.

Comment: You are correct. The code is working if the file is re-open. So, correct way is the locking it has to be in any date change regardless if the file is open by any other user. How do i do that?.... by change the onOpen function to onEdit?. Can i have to onEdit? Can i have two onEdit functions in one script?

Comment: You cannot have to onEdit() functions, but you can incorporate both functionalities in one onEdit() function. See my updated answer. Keep in mind that the each change in the sheet will take some time to update the protections.

Comment: Thanks @ ziganotschka.... now it works fine. By the way... isn't a easier to check which cells contain the "ENDED" text value and then lock & unlock them accordingly instead of checking the date column?. I am aksing because if i change the date and not delete it first the protection it not removes.

Comment: Sure, you can modify the function in a way that the lock&unlock check runs on any edit, no matter what the content in column 2, for this you only need to take this code part out of the inner `if` statement. Just keep in mind that the more often you run the code, the slower it will make the work with your sheet.